# Angular 2 and Asp.Net 5 mvc 6 - authentication practices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, angular, session-cookies

I'm creating my first spa application using angular 2 and asp.net 5 mvc 6. It will be simple app using cookie-based authentication. I know i should use tokens but I don't need to pass authentication to other applications so cookies should be enough.
I also decide to use permission based authorization. Db schema looks like:

```
User ---> Role <----> Permission
```

My api return code 401 when user is not authenticated and 403 when he is authenticated but he don't have permissions to access data

I already implemented this part:
[schema](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/jwt-lt-pyconpl15-151017170324-lva1-app6892/95/jwt-cookiefree-authentication-4-638.jpg?cb=1445199463)

But now I don't know how to handle with user credentials and permissions in client and I have some questions. I just need some guidance.

1. How to store user data in spa after authentication when session is set  ? There are many options. I can call api each time i need user data e.g. username, email or I can fetch it once and store in encrypted cookie or localStorage.
2. The same with user permissions. I want to manage displaying of buttons in template or links in menu etc. due to current user permissions using directives like *ngIf. There also I can store user permissions in localStorage or call api each time route change to get json like:

   ```
   {  
       showEditButton: true,
       showHeader: false 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This project handles all of the above: *https://github.com/chsakell/aspnet5-angular2-typescript* Well worth a look.

Comment: Thanks so much. It was worth to wait a bit for a ready example. I made exactly the same authentication implementation on server side earlier, but I did not know how to connect this with angular spa. That looks great ;)

Comment: Note that as of writing, this project stores your password in plaintext in localstorage which is fairly dangerous. Instead you should typically store a token here and pass it through with every request you want authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

I  store this info in local storage of browser. I save user info (username) object in local storage when user is logging, and clear it when I get Unauthorized responce from api, or when user is log out. And I recommend you to use tokens for SPA. SPA should be stateless. Token auth for api is not only for external providers.

Comment: Thanks, I considered this option but i wasn't sure if it's best way to do this. At the beggining, I wanted to create token auth, but it's difficult for me to create authorization server for tokens and there are practically no examples for new version of asp.net which is still in beta :/

Comment: Try to implement this following this tutorial   http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ and using old VS template. It is about old Web Api, but main features are the same.

Comment: I saw this tutorial, but the main problem is that I don't want to use Identity because its db schema doesn't fit to my - based on permissions :/

Comment: You can use Identity. Especially with new MVC. I use Identity and Mongo. You should implement your own UserStore.